@solana/spl-token dependency keeps giving the error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice'). On just importing the without even using
I'm trying to mint NFT on solana and when using the @solana/spl-token dependency in the frontend it is throwing the below error but when I comment out the @solana/spl-token the error disappears
 
This is the Mint.tsx file 
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import { useAnchorWallet, useConnection } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { Program, AnchorProvider, web3, Idl, setProvider, workspace, Wallet } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import idl from './solana_nft_anchor.json';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, getAssociatedTokenAddress} from '@solana/spl-token';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import { findMasterEditionPda, findMetadataPda, MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID, mplTokenMetadata } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { walletAdapterIdentity } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-signer-wallet-adapters';
import { publicKey } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi';

const programID = new PublicKey('C3j8iHKYvgpoB57XUm5W6zWt9DjH5mkiXngeuGRF96fs');

const MintNFT: FC = () => {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState<string>('');
  const signer = wallet;



  const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSymbolChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSymbol(e.target.value);
  };

  const uploadToIPFS = async (file: File): Promise<string> => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          pinata_api_key: '3f31e87e21efab6b00d7',
          pinata_secret_api_key: '4ef9a8b47bc121b43038a1f1172f02ae9d750b72f97c1b479b5148a2dccd6535',
        },
      });
      console.log(res.data.IpfsHash)
      return `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${res.data.IpfsHash}`;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading to IPFS:', error);
      throw new Error('Failed to upload file to IPFS');
    }
  };

  const handleMint = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (!signer || !file || !name || !symbol) {
      console.error('Wallet not connected, no file selected, or name/symbol not provided');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const uri = await uploadToIPFS(file);
      const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
        commitment: "confirmed",
      });
      const program = new Program(idl as unknown as Idl, programID, provider);

      const mintKeypair = web3.Keypair.generate();

      const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
      .use(walletAdapterIdentity(signer))
      .use(mplTokenMetadata());

      let metadataAccount = findMetadataPda(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(mintKeypair.publicKey),
      })[0];

      let masterEditionAccount = findMasterEditionPda(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(mintKeypair.publicKey),
      })[0];

    const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mintKeypair.publicKey,
        signer.publicKey
    );

        const tx = await program.methods
            .initNft(name, symbol, uri)
            .accounts({
                signer: provider.publicKey,
                mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                associatedTokenAccount,
                metadataAccount,
                masterEditionAccount,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                tokenMetadataProgram: MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            })
            .signers([mintKeypair])
            .rpc();


      alert('NFT minted successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error minting NFT:', error);
      alert('Failed to mint NFT');
    }
  };

Here's is the program in rust I deployed using anchor framework
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    metadata::{
        create_master_edition_v3, create_metadata_accounts_v3, CreateMasterEditionV3,
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3, Metadata,
    },
    token::{mint_to, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount},
};
use mpl_token_metadata::{
    types::DataV2,
};

declare_id!("3SP9gfyt5MeBJUSvxiP85Z9neccFb131nk3A2oEfFVKS"); 

#[program]
pub mod solana_nft_anchor {

    use super::*;

    pub fn init_nft(
        ctx: Context<InitNFT>,
        name: String,
        symbol: String,
        uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // create mint account
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            MintTo {
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.associated_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
            },
        );

        mint_to(cpi_context, 1)?;

        // create metadata account
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                payer: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            },
        );

        let data_v2 = DataV2 {
            name: name,
            symbol: symbol,
            uri: uri,
            seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
            creators: None,
            collection: None,
            uses: None,
        };

        create_metadata_accounts_v3(cpi_context, data_v2, false, true, None)?;

        //create master edition account
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            CreateMasterEditionV3 {
                edition: ctx.accounts.master_edition_account.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                payer: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(),
                token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            },
        );

        create_master_edition_v3(cpi_context, None)?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitNFT<'info> {
    /// CHECK: ok, we are passing in this account ourselves
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub signer: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = signer.key(),
        mint::freeze_authority = signer.key(),
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = signer
    )]
    pub associated_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK - address
    #[account(
        mut,
        address= mpl_token_metadata::accounts::Metadata::find_pda(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub metadata_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: address
    #[account(
        mut,
        address=  mpl_token_metadata::accounts::Metadata::find_pda(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub master_edition_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

github repo: https://github.com/jayeshy14/solana_nft_anchor
